# Crear array de seleccionados (checkbox) EventEmitter en componente padre

Tags: array, angular, checkbox

estoy intentando pasar los valores seleccionados con un checkbox mediante un componente item-hijo a un array en el componente padre para poder así eliminar un conjunto de objetos.

Pasan todos bien pero no consigo crear el array en condiciones, tan sencillo como: si pinchas se agrega el valor y si vuelves a pinchar se borra el valor, pensé que sería más facíl pero llevo ya muchas vueltas.

procesaPropagar(id) {

```
 if (this.capturaCochesId.length === 0) {
  this.capturaCochesId.push(id);
  // this.nuevoArray = this.capturaCochesId.filter((el, index) => this.capturaCochesId.indexOf(el) === index)
} else {
    for (let selec of this.capturaCochesId) {
    if (selec === id) {
      this.capturaCochesId.pop();
    } 
  }
}    
console.log(this.capturaCochesId);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitarás ver si está el elemento en el *array* con la función `includes`.

En caso de que esté, se borra.
Si no se encuentra, se añade.

```
const handleCheck = id => {
    const found = this.capturaCochesId.includes(i => i === id);
    if (found) {
        // Filtra todos aquellos ids que no son el seleccionado
        // Por lo que devuelve un array sin ese.
        this.capturaCochesId = this.capturaCochesId.filter(i => i !== id);
    } else {
        // Si no lo encontramos, se añade
        this.capturaCochesId.push(id);
    }
}
```

No estoy del todo seguro si es lo que necesitas. En cualquier caso, me comentas.
Espero que sirva.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me ha funcionado en parte: Le sobra el "const handleCheck = id => {} ", Muchas Gracias!!!!!

Comment: Sólo es la definición de la función para contextualizar. Bueno, me alegro que te sirva.